# How to host Azure Function App for provider contract testing

Tags: azure-functions, pact, contract, pact-net, azure-functions-isolated

I have in-process Azure Function App (v3). And I want to write a Contract tests for this  Function App (it is Provider) using [Pactnet](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net).
To check that Provider (my Function App) honors pacts I need to host it with some mocked dependencies (like authorization or third parties) on localhost.
In PactNet example [EventApiFixture.cs](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/blob/master/samples/EventApi/Provider.Tests/EventApiFixture.cs) (it is .NET Web API) new host is built and started from tests project. But how is it possible to do with Azure functions? Even if I create isolated Azure function and try to start a host inside my test, I get an error: [image]

Is it possible to run Azure Function App from some other code except Program.cs? Or maybe there are ways to run even in-process Azure Function App (it does not have Program.cs) from Tests project?